# How to do this Firebase Cloud Function I cant get this to work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

In the Cloud Firestore I try to create a Function trigger but I have some problems.

I want the Cloud Firestore Function to respond to writes at this Firebase Realtime databas location:

```
"VISITORS_PRESENCE" : {
    "8PICNP6JBTJDFGiBZYsT" : { // House for sale
      "3b1874ec-02f8-4004-817d-a3c44877473c" : { // The user Id
        "applicationId" : "3b1874ec-02f8-4004-817d-a3c44877473c",
        "last_changed" : 1510859721293,
        "state" : "online",
        "userId" : "testtest@test,com"
      }
    }
  },
```

and simply copy this values/writes into Cloud Firestore Using this functions:
(note this is based on the [Cloud Firestore docs functions get-started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

```
exports.onvisitorPresence = functions.database
    .ref("/VISITORS_PRESENCE/{uid1}/{uid2}").onWrite((event) => {
        // Get the data written to Realtime Database
        const eventStatus = event.data.val();

        // Then use other event data to create a reference to the
        // corresponding Firestore document.
        const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore
        .doc(`VISITORS_PRESENCE/${event.params.uid1}/USERS/{event.params.uid2}`);

        // It is likely that the Realtime Database change that triggered
        // this event has already been overwritten by a fast change in
        // online / offline status, so we'll re-read the current data
        // and compare the timestamps.
        return event.data.ref.once("value").then((statusSnapshot) => {
            return statusSnapshot.val();
        }).then((status) => {
            console.log(status, eventStatus);
            // If the current timestamp for this data is newer than
            // the data that triggered this event, we exit this function.
            if (status.last_changed > eventStatus.last_changed) return;

            // Otherwise, we convert the last_changed field to a Date
            eventStatus.last_changed = new Date(eventStatus.last_changed);

            // ... and write it to Firestore.
            return userStatusFirestoreRef.set(eventStatus);
        });
    });
```

In the Cloud Firestore what this produces is this:

VISITORS_PRESENCE/8PICNP6JBTJDFGiBZYsT/USERS/{event.params.uid2}/
applicationId "3b1874ec-02f8-4004-817d-a3c44877473c"
last_changed November 16, 2017 at 8:15:21 PM UTC+1
state "online"
userId "testtest@test,com"

Here´s a pic:
[image]

I want the `event.params.uid2`in the above to be the "3b1874ec-02f8-4004-817d-a3c44877473c" which is a userId.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is triggered by write operation to the Firebase Realtime Database:

```
exports.onvisitorPresence = functions.database
    .ref("/VISITORS_PRESENCE/{uid1}/{uid2}").onWrite((event) => {
```

To trigger a function by a write to Cloud Firestore you'd use:

```
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
  .document('users/marie').onWrite((event) => {
```

For a longer example, have a look at the [documentation for triggering Cloud Functions from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

Answer (score 0):

I did a smaaall error. I forgot the $ sign

> .doc(`VISITORS_PRESENCE/${event.params.uid1}/USERS/{event.params.uid2}`);
>
> .doc(`VISITORS_PRESENCE/${event.params.uid1}/USERS/${event.params.uid2}`);

Now the Cloud Firestore data looks ok:

VISITORS_PRESENCE/8PICNP6JBTJDFGiBZYsT/USERS/8PICNP6JBTJDFGiBZYsT/
applicationId "3b1874ec-02f8-4004-817d-a3c44877473c"
last_changed November 16, 2017 at 8:15:21 PM UTC+1
state "online"
userId "testtest@test,com"